# POP!_OS - Python3-repolib Error on Upgrade

Tags: symlink, python3, software-updates, pop-os, dist-upgrade

*POP!OS_22.04*

**TL;DR**

**Ran into a weird error with a specific package `python3-repolib`on Lenovo Laptop. This also happened this morning on my partner's iMac device after she attempted to upgrade to 22.04. It failed, reverted back to 21.10 and now has the same issue with this package.**

Was working on fiance's laptop. She upgraded to POP 22.04. Attempted to do an update/upgrade and received the following error:

```
Setting up python3-repolib (1.5.2~1651157034~22.04~e2261d9) ...
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/add-apt-repository': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/apt-add-repository': File exists
dpkg: error processing package python3-repolib (--configure):
installed python3-repolib package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
python3-repolib
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I looked online for this issue but only one other person had it and it apparently just "went away".
I did notice other online posts, mostly ubuntu (why I am here), said to reconfigure and reinstall python3. Tried that. I still get the error above. I attempted the following:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Same error code ending in `python3-repolib` still being the problem. I removed the package then reinstalled it, same issue. After banging my head against the table, I thought I'd see where the symlinks are that keep being mentioned when I attempt to do anything.

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/add-apt-repository': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/apt-add-repository': File exists

 find /usr/bin/add-apt-repository -type l -ls
   3801127      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           35 Apr 25 20:52 /usr/bin/add-apt-repository -> /usr/lib/repolib/add-apt-repository

find /usr/bin/apt-add-repository -type l -ls
  3801128      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           35 Apr 25 20:52 /usr/bin/apt-add-repository -> /usr/lib/repolib/add-apt-repository
```

Now I am here and have no idea what to do next other than see what unlinking the files will do to the system. But I'd rather get a second opinion before possibly borking this install.

**UPDATE**

Partner updated system successfully then attempted to upgrade to 22.04. Upgrade failed, then reverted back to 21.04. Now receiving

`Errors were encountered while processing:`

`python3-repolib`

Is this an issue with Python3 itself or an issue with Pop? I assume others must be having this issue since 22.10 is still fairly new. What should I do next? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue here, I made a post on the Pop!_OS reddit, sharing the link with you and posting the link for this thread on my post:

https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/ues9ru/updating_error_2204/

Excerpt from the [reddit post by u/TonyDTN]:

---

Two options:

1. Following the instructions of u/Carpol_v2 on the comments now updated fine. So, in order on the terminal:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
sudo mv /usr/bin/add-apt-repository /
sudo mv /usr/bin/apt-add-repository /
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then reboot and check Pop!_Shop or rerun `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to check.

2. Following the instructions of u/JAY0S on the comments:

Run in terminal:

```bsh
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-repolib.* 
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Then rerun `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to check.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I found your post on Reddit and did it. It worked like a charm. Nothing is broken and my fiance is happy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer/maintainer for Repolib on Pop_OS.

This is being caused by a bug in the repolib preinstallation script and a PR is open to get it fixed which should be released soon. In the meantime, if you are experiencing this issue you can workaround it by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo unlink /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
sudo unlink /usr/bin/apt-add-repository
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

This issue should only be occurring on certain subsets of Pop installs, and will only occur if the `software-properties-common` package is removed prior to installing/upgrading/reinstalling the `python3-repolib` package. If you're concerned about hitting this issue before performing an upgrade, the following should ensure that you are good to go (without causing damage to your system if it would not have caused problems):

```
if [[ `dpkg -s software-properties-common | grep 'Status'` = *'installed'* ]]; then echo Your system is not susceptible to the bug!; else sudo unlink /usr/bin/add-apt-repository; sudo unlink /usr/bin/apt-add-repository; echo Bug mitigated; fi
```

Simply copy-paste the entire command into a terminal and press enter to check/mitigate the issue. It will check whether your system has the trigger condition or not (missing `software-properties-common`) and then remove the offending files if so.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out! I will keep this in mind if it happens again. The first answer on this sub actually got the system up and running. But I hope for your fix in the future. Cheers!